# Android Studio styles.xml Error

Tags: android, android-studio

Ever since I updated android studio to the newest version I've been having this problem:

*Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> C:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\materialtest\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:8:9: Error: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.*

The only problem code appears to be:

```
  <style name = "AppTheme.Base" parent = "Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    < item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    < item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    < item name="colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item> </style>
```

Comment: you need close <style name="" /> or  </style>

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the style with a forward slash.

```
<style name = "AppTheme.Base" parent = "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your style tag with a forward slash `/>`

It would look something like:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```

or close it with a style tag

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"></style>
```

This link to [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) might provide more detailed information